# Legalization fees per document for Taiwanese visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, taiwan

I am hoping to travel to Taiwan. I came across http://www.sticholidays.com/sticholidays/packages/visa-info.php?pkgID=895 where it says:

> Legalisation fees per document (Normal)   Rs. 900/-

I understand I need at least 7 documents.

The applicant should have a passport valid for at least 6 months from the intended date of entry into Taiwan, along with both old and new passport are required.

Photocopy of the applicant's passport.

1. One visa form (The applicants need to fill online visa form at the website https://visawebapp.boca.gov.tw&bb and take the printout of filled online form, should be signed by the applicant).

   Two recent passport-size photographs (35 x 45 mm) against a white background, taken within last six months.
2. A cover letter from the company or the applicant mentioning the purpose of the visit, designation of the visitor and the intended duration of stay (if applicants require multiple entry visa, tentative traveling date should be mentioned. (in original).
3. An invitation should come as a fax from Taiwan with Taiwan company's fax number showing on it. It should also mention the travel dates on which the applicant is traveling. This invitation should be signed manually as signatures in form of a stamp will not be acceptable.
4. Copies of Income Tax Returns for the past 3 years and salary slips of the last 6 months.
5. Details of the contact person in Taiwan.
6. Original bank statement for a period of 3 months. The statement should have a bank seal on each page with signatures of the bank's authorised signatory.
7. Confirmed round-trip air ticket and hotel booking in Taiwan.

So should I be looking at 7*900 = INR 6,300 in addition to the INR 3,000 for the visa or am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 1):

In general, legalization is used to authenticate or certify a document so another country will recognize/accept it, e.g., certificates of birth, marriage, divorce; business contracts, export certificates. The site you've linked to is of a travel and tour company.

It directs you to apply directly to [Taiwan's Bureau of Consular Affairs](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-158-253-46961-2.html) where what is required is clearer:

> **Visitor Visa for Visiting Purpose**
>
> - Completed & signed application form: Please access the website: https://visawebapp.boca.gov.tw/ to fill out application form online and print it out.
> - Two passport-size photos in color within 6 months: Photos with a  white color background
> - Passport (original & photocopy): Valid for 6 months with blank pages
> - Invitation Letter: Provided by inviting organization
> - Evidence of funds: e.g. Bank statement
> - Travel Itinerary
> - Other additional documents may be required during processing: Ticket, electronic ticket or proof of a travel agency

Items which you *may* be asked to have legalized might be the copy of your passport and, possibly, the bank statements if not originals with each page stamped by bank officials.

You'll find the visa fees at document at the foot of the [Visa Fees](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-146-252-2e20c-2.html) page, as a downloadable pdf.